# Open Popup with dynamicly generated Html from CodeBehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, popup, code-behind

At a certain point i have a dynamicly generated string with html in my code-behind.
I want to open a popup with has that html as its source.

I have tried the following:
I created this method on my `.aspx` site (Javascript):

```
    function OpenWindowWithHtml(html, title) {
            var myWindow = window.open('', title);
            myWindow.document.write(html);
            myWindow.focus();
     }
```

And in the code-behind i have this:

```
    Response.Write("OpenPopupWithHtml(\"" + html + "\", \"" + title + "\");");
```

But when i try to execute this i get an error.
Does anybody see, what i do wrong here?
Or does somebody know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

on button click it shoudl be like this

```
protected void btnAbct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", "OpenPopupWithHtml('" + html + "', '" + title + "');");
}
```

---

To execute the code ie. function you written in javascript

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
   "newWindow", "OpenPopupWithHtml('" + html + "', '" + title + "');");
```

---

you can register client script like this

```
if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("exampleScript"))
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "exampleScript","
<script language = "'javascript'">
alert('you just registered the start up script')
</script>
");
```

from the code behind file of asp.net

To Open pop-Up window , just replace this line in above code

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
   "newWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>",
         "mypage.html"));
```

Check this for detail : [Register Client script in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19484/Register-Client-script-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: But i want to open the popup as soon, as i have that html.

Comment: @TorbenL. - not getting you ..you want to open it on page load ?? than just write code in page load function

Comment: No. A user clicks on a button and the a whole bunch of stuff is done which results in an html-string. And as soon as i have this string i want to open the popup. I dont want to wait for any action of the user. And i also do not have any link. Just the html.

Comment: @TorbenL. - if i m getting you correctly you want to open popup on button click than you just need to write down the above code in button click event in code behind file ...

Comment: @Pranay_Rana But it does not open. The code just runs through and nothing happens.

Comment: @TorbenL. - try edited answer i just replace the method "RegisterClientScriptBlock" in button click